# How to find the area of the triangle using basic codes such like:

Tags: javascript

Hi guys im a grade 10 student and was asked to create a basic like calculator to solve for the area of the triangle, but i really dont know how.I can do it with the use of a radio button but my teacher said to do it without the radio input. My codes works fine but if i press clear and input a value to the base and height, it will say syntax error...please can you help me? also whenever i dont put a value on base and height,it says 0 instead of syntax error,so please help me....(also sorry about earlier, im just new to this site)
this is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>hfsabfhsabfihs</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function checkbutton() {
      var num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
      var num2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
      if (document.form1.checked == false) {
        alert("Syntax Error")
      } else {
        alert(num1 * num2 / 2);
      }
    }

    function clearbutton() {
      document.form1.checked = false;
      var num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
      var num2 = document.getElementById("input2").value = "";
    }
    //-->
  </script>
  <form name="form1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Base</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="input1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Height</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="input2" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Compute" onclick="checkbutton()">
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearbutton()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the syntax error message and see which part of the code that you need to fix

Comment: It's pretty open and shut: you set `document.form1.checked` to `false`, and then you show a "Syntax Error" alert if `document.form1.checked` is `false`...

Comment: Check the edits

Answer (score 0):

problem is on clear function function

```
function clearbutton()
            {
                // document.form1.checked= false;
                var num1 = document.getElementById("input1").value="";
                var num2 = document.getElementById("input2").value="";
            }
```

you are getting this error because you have set a variable here i.e **form1.checked**. either remove this variable or change its value on calculation function

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps:

```js
// vairbale
const baseInput = document.querySelector("#input1")
const heightInput = document.querySelector("#input2")
const coputeBTn = document.querySelector("#Compute")
const areaTriangle = (base, height) =>{
    let total =""
    let error = false
    let errorMessage = ""
    if(base != "" && height != ""){
        error = false
        total = base * height / 2
    }else{
        error = true
        errorMessage = "Please fill all inputs."
        return errorMessage
    }
    return total
}

// Calling Function
coputeBTn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
console.log(areaTriangle(Number(baseInput.value), Number(heightInput.value)))
})
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Base</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input1" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Height</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="input2" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" id="Compute" value="Compute">
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearbutton()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```